# A hat salesman asks 「帽子を買いませんか?」. Is this an invitation, or a negative question?

Tags: grammar, negation, invitation

In various grammar resources, I've read that a present/future-tense volitional verb, in negative-question form (買いませんか？) becomes an **invitation** pattern, unless ~の(ですか) is added.

「買いませんか?」 = invitation.
「買わないの(ですか)?」 = negative present/future-tense question.

Based on past experience, invitation seems to mean the speaker and listener doing something together. 「朝ご飯を食べませんか?」 "What do you say to having lunch **with me**?" 「テニスをしませんか?」"Will you play tennis **with me**?" 「ズームで話しませんか?」 "Shall **we** talk over Zoom?"

But I'm getting held up on an example I saw in a beginner-level storybook, of a hat salesman in a marketplace shouting 「帽子を買いませんか?」

Based on the rules above, this should be an invitation, but obviously only the listener(s) will be doing any hat-buying. It isn't a shared activity. Instead it just sounds like a negative question: "Won't you buy a hat?"

So, which one of the 2 options below reflects this situation?

(a) ...ませんか invitation patterns don't necessarily have to include the speaker participating in a shared activity. Depending on context, ...ませんか could just be an invitation for the listener alone to do something.

(b) ...ませんか with a volitional verb may not always be an invitation pattern. Sometimes, depending on context, it's just a negative question, even without ~の(ですか).

Comment: Think about *why don't you...?*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both (a) and (b) are correct. There is no such rule that ～しませんか always implies "together". 買いませんか is typically a simple suggestion, "Why don't you buy it?"

But depending on the context, the same sentence can be a confirmation, "So you won't buy it?", too. 買わないのですか can sound like the speaker is slightly dubious or disappointed because of the の's function of seeking clarification, whereas 買いませんか is more neutral.